# A well-documented KOMA-script template/example for 2021?

Tags: koma-script, templates, examples

Does anybody know of well-documented and current (as of 2020/2021) KOMA-script templates or examples? (I am talking mainly about the article/report/book flavors `scrartcl`, `scrreprt`, `scrbook` here: everything you'd use to write a “paper”, for want of a better term.)

The documentation is, put mildly, not for the impatient (or the faint of the heart, for that matter. And as a German native speaker I am not even fazed by the lack of full English docs.)

The questions on this forum and elsewhere always seem to be the same, too:

- There is too much/too little space before/after a paragraph (part, section, subsection, …)
- How can I modify fonts in terms of size, boldness, (not) using serifs, etc.
- How can I modify headers/footers (using `scrlayer-scrpage` instead of `fancyhdr`)
- How can I add to/modify my TOC/Bibliography/List of Tables etc. (without `tocloft`}
- … to be continued.

I have seen a few templates out there, but they were sparsely commented, if at all, often using hackish and outdated approaches. Which brings me to my question: Are there any good, current examples? If they exist, or were to be created, we should collect them and make them more easily accessible. I propose a new tag `koma-script-example` for this purpose.

Comment: You can read the complete documentation in german.

Comment: Your question is hardly answerable, as you don't seem to understand what a LaTeX template is. Or how LaTeX works.

Comment: @Johannes_B: I could. And I have read large chunks of it. I still think there could (and should) be a less painful way. I am by no means computer illiterate, but it takes me far longer than it should. Don't call it a template, then: examples of best practice, if you will.

Comment: The problem is: What of the 565 pages of the manual  merit more understandable  examples? For some users the only relevant information could be that `book` must be replaced by  `scrbook` in the first line. For others, a madly long template of insane complexity still will not cover every possibility.

Comment: The only I know: https://github.com/fmarotta/kaobook.  Not sure if it is current.

Comment: Thanks, I was ware of `kaobook`. It's really more of a new class, though, so not exactly what I was looking for. I like the KOMA classes and use them regularly, but I consider the documentation, extensive as it may be, its one great weakness.